# Question About Tensor Products over Different Base Rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I can't prove the following remark which appears in Matsumura's 'Commutative Ring Theory':

> If $B$ is an $A$-algebra and $M$ and $N$ are $B$-modules, $M\otimes_{B}N$ is the quotient of $M\otimes_{A}N$ by the submodule generated by elements of the form $bx\otimes_{A}y-x\otimes_{A}by$.

I think I was able to do it using the universal property (in a completely straightforward fashion), but I am suspicious of this as I couldn't do it by proving directly that $\ker(M\otimes_{A}N\rightarrow M\otimes_{B}N)$ is generated by these elements.

Comment: One can prove directly that the kernel is what is given by directly using the definition of tensor product. We have $M \otimes_A N$ is the free $A$-module on $M \times N$ with some relations $R$ whereas $M \otimes_B N$ is the free $B$-module on $M \times N$ with some relations $Q$. One shows that one can get all relations $Q$ by using the relations from $R$ and the relations $(bx \otimes_A y - x \otimes_A by$. 

This is not very precise but I hope it leads you in the right direction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the universal property for $\otimes_A$ one gets a map
$$ M\otimes_AN\to M\otimes_BN, \quad m\otimes_A n\mapsto m\otimes_B n. $$
This sends the submodule $L$ generated by all $mb\otimes_A n-m\otimes_A bn$ to zero, so we get the induced map
$$ (M\otimes_AN)/L\to M\otimes_BN, \quad m\otimes_An+L \mapsto m\otimes_Bn. $$

We can construct the inverse map using the universal property for $\otimes_B$. For, the map $$ M\times N\to (M\otimes_AN)/L, \quad (m,n)\mapsto m\otimes_A n+L $$
is $B$-bilinear, so induces the map
$$ M\otimes_BN\to (M\otimes_AN)/L, \quad m\otimes_Bn \mapsto m\otimes_An+L. $$
These two maps are clearly mutually inverse, as required.